# How can gstreamer play PCM file, programming(C prefer), not gst-launch

Tags: c, gstreamer, pcm

I can play a PCM(RAW data, NOT wav format file) file, using the following command:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=./44K_16bits.pcm ! audio/x-raw-int, width=16, depth=16, endianness=1234, channels=2, rate=44100, signed=true ! alsasink
```

How can this work in programming(C will be great)?

I tried to link the filesrc and convert + alsasink.

But the pipeline didn't work. What's the part `audio/x-raw-int`? The caps setting to filesrc's "Source" or convert's "Sink"?

Answer (score 2):

It is a capsfilter, so you need to put a capsfilter in there and set its "caps" property. The launch is just doing a simplification of:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=./44K_16bits.pcm ! capsfilter caps="audio/x-raw-int, width=16, depth=16, endianness=1234, channels=2, rate=44100, signed=true" ! alsasink
```